# Am I right in playing this notes?

Tags: piano, practice, learning

[image]
[image][image]

I am a piano learner without a teacher. I learn by practice and think.

I came across a difficult note and don’t know how to play.

I have attached the photos.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

The E is displaced in the music so it can be seen clearly, but all four notes are played at the same time, and your fingering is a practical way of doing it.

I'd probably use the sustain pedal in order to prepare the next chord, even though that's not explicitly noted in the score.

Answer (score 4):

Since the key signature is 2#, F♯ and C♯, all notes played will be white keys - *except* the accidental G♯. So, you're playing B, D, E, G♯. All correct. The fingering is as good as any, and if you've tried others and that's the best, stick with it.

Th chord is E7, 2nd inversion. Your problem *may* be that the E is out of line. That's simply because it's easier to read than it would be if all heads were on the same side of the stem. All four notes are played simultaneously, at the beginning of that bar, on beat 1, along with the two E notes in the bass clef.

Comment: Tim, so I can make things more complete in the future, what does this answer say that my answer does not?

Comment: Probably the same things, except identifying the chord involved. However, often answers are couched to say the same thing in different ways, and OP  (and others) will understand one better than another. I try not to duplicate answers, but to put my answers in the way I hope will be understood - at least by some. I know questions can be dupes - answers too?